# which field should i use to allow more than one comment?

Tags: python, django

i am trying to add comments to the auction page but only allow **adding a comment per auction** which models field should i use to allow **more than one comment?**

when i try add more than one comment in the admin page the page show it:

> Comments with this Auction already exists.

models.py:

```
class Auction_listings(models.Model):
    product_image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="others")
    product_price = models.FloatField() #IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_title}"


class Bids(models.Model):
    auction = models.OneToOneField(Auction_listings, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bid_value = models.FloatField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"by {self.username} in {self.auction}: {self.bid_value}"


class Comments(models.Model):
    auction = models.OneToOneField(Auction_listings, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"by {self.username} in {self.auction} on {self.date}"
```

thank you in advanced

Comment: In the `Comments` model change auction from `OneToOneField` to `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use OneToOne field you will connect one comment to one auction (One-to-One). for more than one comment per auction you should use Foreign-Key field like this:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction_listings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"by {self.username} in {self.auction} on {self.date}"
```